# Help identifying chinese marks and signstures on porcelain and pottery

Tags: translation

I bought a collection of antique porcelain and pottery and I've identified a lot but I have a couple that are stumping me, no matter how much research I do. Can anyone help identify these?[image]

[image]

Comment: I can't identify the mark in picture 1, it's so scribble, and I don't think there are any Chinese characters like this in picture 2. They may be some calligraphy, or the unique signature of the maker, or just be some marks

Answer (score 2):

According to @dROOOze's suggestion, the first image seems to be 錦書, or 錦畫. I agree with this reading, especially since it fits the context of inscription on a colourful piece of pottery. The character in the second image consists of 辵 (with an extra stroke on top) and 巾 in seal script, but that character does not exist.

In addition to the difficulty in recognizing these as characters, the calligraphic style of the characters seem incongruous. The writer in the first image seems to be aiming for a running-hand style, as evidenced by the connecting strokes in the second character. However, the left side of the first character distinctly lacks connection between the horizontal strokes, which would have been written in succession therefore likely connected. This increases the likelihood that the inscriptions are produced by someone who is imitating existing calligraphic works, but themselves unfamiliar or at least unskilled with the practice.

Comment: The first picture says "錦畫" or "錦書".

Comment: @dROOOze That does sound quite likely. I will update my answer. Thank you!